# Wrong answer Trapezoid rule in C

Tags: c, function

Ok so this program is compiling and running EXCEPT it is outputting an answer of zero for the area. (Note this function is part of a main that calls it). I've included the shortest of the functions as an example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define pi 3.1415927;

//Function to convert degrees to radians
float TrapezoidRule(float);
float SimpsonsRule(float);
float GaussQuadrature(float);

int main() {

int userInput, N;
float area, error;

        printf("Choose which method to use to calculate the area of the function sin(x) from 0 to pi:\n");
        printf("Enter 1 to use the Trapezoid Rule, enter 2 to use Simpson's Rule, enter 3 to use Gauss' Quadrature.\n");
        scanf("%d", &userInput);
        printf("\nEnter the number of intervals to use to calculate the area.\n");
        scanf("%d", &N);

        if (userInput == 1) {                //Call Trapezoid rule function
           printf("You are in this loop\n");
           TrapezoidRule(area);
           }
        if (userInput == 2) {
           SimpsonsRule(area);
           }
        if (userInput == 3) {
           GaussQuadrature(area);
        }

        error = ((fabs(area - 2.0))/2.0)* 100;

        //Print the area calculated using the chosen method 
        printf("\narea using chosen method = %.7f. Actual area = 2.0\n", area);
        printf("The percentage error for your chosen method = %.7f\n", error);

return 0;

}
```

The Gauss Quadrature function looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double pi = 3.1415927;

int main (void) {

float area, a, b, h, k, error;

a = 0.0; 
b = pi; 
h = (b - a)/2;
k = a + h;

area = h * (sin(k + (h/sqrt(3.0))) + sin(k + (h/sqrt(3.0))));


//error = fabs(((area-2.0)/2.0) * 100);

printf("Area according to Gauss Quadrature = %.8f, True area = 2.0\n Error = %.8f percent\n", area, error);


return 0; 
}
```

Using printf statements, I can see that the function is being called correctly, but the area isnt' being calculated correctly in the function. Might this be related to how the function is called in the main? Sorry I'm very much a beginner programming and am confused in how to properly call and use functions. Thanks very much for any help!

Comment: What's the second program for? Is the problem with the `TrapezoidRule` function? How does *that* function look like?

Comment: This is unclear - is your second snippet another program or your function? If its your function, why does it redefine main?

Comment: Also, you should read about passing argument *by value* and *by reference* and their difference, as that is most likely your problem here.

Answer (score 1):

As the functions `float TrapezoidRule(float)` is not defined, it is difficult to know for sure, but I'm guessing that the function returns the area. Also the N-variable is read, but never used - is it an input variable to the function(s)?

If that is the case, you need to store the returned result in the area variable: `area = TrapezoidRule(N);`

Answer (score 0):

```
//A function like 
float TrapezoidRule(float);
```

Should have a return statement returning the area.

When calling this function
use a variable like,

```
float newarea = TrapezoidRule( area) ;
```

now 'newarea' will store the value that was returned from function trapezoidrule